# Xcode 4.6 + Cordova / PhoneGap 2.5

Tags: xcode, cordova

Yes,this is yet another question around icons in Xcode with Cordova.I have spent most of the day trying to track down the cause of these issues and have acted on everything I've found but the errors keep coming. 
There seems to be an issue around:The capitalization of the 'i' in 'icon',along with how that filename is passed to Xcode,and the caching thereof.There is a further and more fundamental error that just seems to be a plain bug.This is what I do after receiving the '`unable to verify icon dimensions, no icon found'`

error: 1.Delete the archive 2.Product -> clean 3.Product -> archive. 4.Check 'Resources' (should be in resources -> icons, where 'resources' is in the folder on the same level as the codeproj folder, right?). 5.Check 'Build phases' for any items in red. Delete if I find any. 6. Organizer - Archives. This is the interesting bit - so long as my icons begin with lowercase 'i', I'll see my big icon in the organizer window. If a change the icon name to begin with a capital 'I' (which is what most people suggest),that icon doesn't appear.But the error message is always the same, and refers to "Icon.png' (for example), not 'icon.png'. Apologies for the length, and please don't suggest anything that's already been suggested! seriously, I've tried them all, and it's doing my head in.Many thanks in advance.

Comment: updated to latest xcode (4.6.2). Same problem.

Comment: OK, I think I fixed it. I updated to the latest xcode (above) + the latest cordova (2.7). Rebuilt the project. And then (I think this is the important bit), replaced the icons (resources/icons) before I started xcode, code signed, archived etc. I hope this helps someone.